# How To Make A Random Image Generator For Website

Tags: javascript, html

So my aim is to have a random image generator for a website. So people just click the button, and it loads 1 image out of a the image "bank". When i say bank i mean like the file where there located, and would it matter how many image chooses there are?
is there any javascript or html codes for this?

-thanks.

Comment: have you tried any of our solutions???

Comment: Sorry Working atm, but will! very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to do this is as follows:

Name all the pictures with the same name but different number extension: `img_1, img_2, img_3`...etc.

Define a function that randomly create a img (src) name. For example, if you have 10 images:

The HTML code:

```
<img id="imageid" src="">
```

And the JS code:

```
function randomImg(){
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
var imgName = "img_" + randomNumber;
document.getElementById("imageid").src= YOUR_IMG_PATH + "/" + imgName ;
}
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT: If you have a .jpg or .png image, make sure to include that in the function or it won't work. For example for a JPG image:

```
function randomImg(){
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
    var imgName = "img_" + randomNumber + ".jpg";
    document.getElementById("greenbox").src= "YOUR_IMG_PATH" + "/" + imgName ;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From my [first hit on Google](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut118.shtml)...

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

/*
Random Image Script- By JavaScript Kit (http://www.javascriptkit.com) 
Over 400+ free JavaScripts here!
Keep this notice intact please
*/

function random_imglink(){
var myimages=new Array()
//specify random images below. You can have as many as you wish
myimages[1]="image1.gif"
myimages[2]="image2.gif"
myimages[3]="image3.gif"
myimages[4]="image4.gif"
myimages[5]="image5.gif"
myimages[6]="image6.gif"

var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
if (ry==0)
ry=1
document.write('<img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" border=0>')
}
random_imglink()
//-->
</script>

<p align="center">This free script provided by<br />
<a href="http://javascriptkit.com">JavaScript
Kit</a></p>
```

Comment: um... why exactly are you doing the array like that? I feel like it'd be a lot more concise to just do `var myimages = ["image1.gif", "image2.gif", "image3.gif", "image4.gif", "image5.gif", "image6.gif"];`